# I try to navigate page through clicking an image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. Im trying to navigate page through clicking an image but it keep messing around. [image]
below show before and after i make changes[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide us with more details regarding your problem?

Comment: By messing what do you mean? Is navigation to a page not working?

Comment: please use inkwell widget

Answer (score 1):

you can use `inkwell`

inkwell has so many property like color etc.....
it's a rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.

```
 InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        focusColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
        onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/you'r destination page");
        },
        child: Image.asset(" you'r image path ")
        )
```

it provides tapping section , using onTap you can tap what ever you want

**OR**

you can use `GestureDetector`

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/you'r destination page");
        },
         child: Image.asset(" you'r image path ")
        )
```

it also recognize gestures that correspond to its non-null callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your Image with the gesture detector, right now they are in the same column but not together ie

```
GestureDetector(
onTap: DoNavigationHere,
Child: Image.asset
)
```